# How can I feed internet from guest (pfSense) to another guest (Linux Mint) on Windows 7 (Host)?

Tags: virtualbox, pfsense

I found a good post from a guy who managed to install a firewall (pfSense) in a virtual machine (VirtualBox) on Windows 7 (Host) to protect his computer using "Microsoft Loopback adapter". You can read this post here:

http://timita.org/wordpress/2011/07/29/protect-your-windows-laptop-with-pfsense-and-virtualbox-part-1-preamble/

I plan to go further by apply a filter, using pfSense, to Windows so it will only have access to Windows Update and to install, in a second virtual machine, Linux Mint to browse the net.

My question is: How can I feed internet to Linux (Guest 2) from pfSense (Guest 1) on Windows 7 (Host) using VirtualBox?

Please note that I'm a total noob in virtualisation.